# How to search a NSArray filled with UIImageViews for a certain image property?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, nsarray

I have an NSArray filled with UIImageViews.  I want to do an `indexOfObject` call on the array, but using a UIImage as the search parameter.  So I want to find the index of a UIImageView based on it's image property.  Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to customize the iteration thru the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`:

```
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(UIImageView *imgv, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    *stop = (imgv.image == myImage);
    return *stop;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes more memory but you can store an NSArray of your image objects that have the same order as your image views. Then it is a simple mapping of indexes.